# What does *pCmd mean in API function

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new into programming and working on a QT cnc gui based on an API.

Example in API:

api.h

```
/*
 * Name   : CncSetSpindleOutput
 * In     : onOff and direction Value,
 *          direction can be 0 or 1, of value -1 it is ignored.
 *          absSpeed
 * Out    : -
 * Return : See CNC_RC values
 * Descr  : Set SpindleSpeed
*/
CNC_RC EXP2DF __stdcall CncSetSpindleOutput(int onOff, int direction, double absSpeed);
```

And in my QT app:

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_spindleOn_clicked()
{
    CncSetSpindleOutput(1, 1, 1000);
}
```

And it all works as expected. But following function I cant get to work.
What does *pCmd mean?

api.h

```
* Name   : Cnc3DPrintCommand
* In     : pCmd command/reply for 3D printer, see description of CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND
* Out    : -
* Return : See CNC_RC values
* Descr  :
*/
CNC_RC EXP2DF __stdcall Cnc3DPrintCommand(CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND *pCmd);
```

api_types.h

```
typedef enum
{
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_ONOFF     = 1,
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_STANDBY   = 2,
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_PIDONOFF  = 3,
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_TEMP_MAX  = 4,
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_TEMP      = 5,
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_TEMP_WAIT = 6,
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_PARS      = 7,
    CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_POWER     = 8,
    CNC_3DP_SET_HEATBED_ONOFF      = 9,
    CNC_3DP_SET_HEATBED_STANDBY    = 10,
    CNC_3DP_SET_HEATBED_PIDONOFF   = 11,
    CNC_3DP_SET_HEATBED_TEMP_WAIT  = 12,
    CNC_3DP_SET_HEATBED_TEMP       = 13,
    CNC_3DP_SET_HEATBED_PARS       = 14,
    CNC_3DP_SET_HEATBED_POWER      = 15,
    CNC_3DP_SET_WPFAN_ONOFF        = 16,
    CNC_3DP_SET_WPFAN_STANDBY      = 17,
    CNC_3DP_SET_WPFAN_POWER        = 18,
    CNC_3DP_SET_WPFAN_PARS         = 19,
    CNC_3DP_ALL_OFF                = 20,
    CNC_3DP_DEFAULT_PARS           = 21,
    CNC_3DP_EXTRUDER_RES_OVERRIDE  = 22,
    CNC_3DP_UPDATE_SHOW_AS_GO_FEED = 23
} CNC_3DP_COMMAND_ID;


typedef struct CNC_3DP_ONOFF_DATA
{
    CNC_ONOFF onOff;

} CNC_3DP_ONOFF_DATA;

typedef struct CNC_3DP_FLOATVAL_DATA
{
    float value;

} CNC_3DP_FLOATVAL_DATA;


typedef struct
{
    CNC_3DPRINTING_TEMP_PID_PARS pidPars;
    CNC_3DP_ONOFF_DATA onOffVal;
    CNC_3DP_FLOATVAL_DATA floatVal;

} CNC_3DP_CMD_DATA;

typedef struct _CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND
{
    CNC_3DP_COMMAND_ID cmdID;
    CNC_3DP_CMD_DATA   d;
} CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND;
```

Cnc3DPrintCommand() expects a single argument, and I would be very happy if someone have time to give me an example of eg. CNC_3DP_SET_EXTRUDER_TEMP  .

thanks /
JCN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND *pCmd
```

Here, `pCmd` is a pointer to an object of type `CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND` which is defined as the following:

```
typedef struct _CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND
{
    CNC_3DP_COMMAND_ID cmdID;
    CNC_3DP_CMD_DATA   d;
} CNC_3DPRINTING_COMMAND;
```